# $scope.object is undefined a $http promise

Tags: angularjs

I bit new to Angular, using controller, factory that keeps methods for the $http requests.

--------------In Service------------------------------

```
        factory.getContract = function(guid) {
            return $http
                .get(Configuration.apiurl + '/contracts/' + guid, { headers: {"accesstoken": 'XXXXXXXXXX'}})
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response;
                });
        };
```

--------------- In Controller ------------------

```
$scope.getContract = function (guid) {
            ContractService.getContract(guid).then(
                function (response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    $scope.contract = {
                        contract_status: data.contract_status,
                        car: data.car,
                        properties: data.data
                    };
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log('Error while loading the contract,', response);
                }
            );
        };



if ($state.includes('contracts.edit')) {
            $scope.getContract($stateParams.guid);
            // In this controller, i check if requesting route is the Edit then get contract data. When i do this it works and fill the form with correct information. BUT AS I TRY TO ACCESS $scope.contract in console it says undefined
            console.log($scope.contract);
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: http is asynchronous. You can't expect the response to have been received right after you have sent the request. Put the console.log() line into the function passed to then().

Comment: @JBNizet is right, in your code contract is logged firstly, and then filled with data. If you want to debug it, try to put console.log() in the promise, directly after filling contract object.

Comment: i think you need to remove the then function in the factory function, you return the http.get and then in the controller do the (then function) as you are doing

Comment: You all are right, I took it wrong. Actually I was trying to access ng-model="contract.contract_status" as $scope.contract.contract_status, it throws "Cannot read property 'contract_status' of undefined"

So, my question is when ng-model input exists then why can't I access it.

Comment: I works now :) I moved the logic into .then that i want to be executed at edit action :)

Thanks you all for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

$http.get is returning Promise, so just remove .then part from your factory if you want to execute callback inside controller:

```
factory.getContract = function(guid) {
        return $http.get(Configuration.apiurl + '/contracts/' + guid, 
               { headers: 
                    {"accesstoken": 'XXXXXXXXXX'}
                });
}
```